# simple xero api oauth2 request

Tags: php, xero-api

I am trying to perform a simple oauth2 request in PHP for the Xero API. The code request works however when I attempt to request a token I receive the following error:

```
 "error":"invalid_client"
```

My header for the token request looks as follows:

```
"Authorization: Basic WQGd1xX==" 
"content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

I am following this guide https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/auth-flow point 3) Exchange the code. Is my header correct or am I missing something? I am using the php function base64_encode as follows:

```
$auth=base64_encode(OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID + ":" + OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET)
```

Comment: Does [this help](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/troubleshooting) ?

Comment: @vivek not really it says the following - "If the client_id or client_secret you pass in are incorrect then you will receive this response." These parameters are definitely correctly I am just not sure as to how the pass the client_id and secret into the header. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you try the same using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) passing your client ID and secret and see if it passes through? Just a check to make sure there aren't any redundant space issues in strings etc.

Comment: Thanks will give it a go. I see that there is no documentation for postman on oauth2 for xero api.

Comment: It might not be. Postman is just a simple API testing tool without having you to code anything.

Comment: thanks it worked in Postman, i will see what the request.

Comment: Good to hear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the function in php

```
base64_encode(OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID.":".OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
```

I also need to pass this in curl_setopt_array

```
CURLOPT_CAINFO => $caFile
```